# Auto-detect the start date and end date to store the day of the week, start time and end time in the day block

Tags: c#, datetime, dayofweek

I have a problem auto-detecting the start date and end date to store the day of the week, start time, and end time in `DayBlock` objects. Why do I need to auto-detect? Because `startDate` and `endDate` are selected by users. In the future, they cannot be hardcoded. I just know the hard-coded way like below:

```cs
//startDate = 22 Nov 2022 05:00 PM
//endDate = 25 Nov 2022 12:00 PM

class DayBlock
{
  public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; set; }
  public TimeSpan Start { get; set; }
  public TimeSpan End { get; set; }
}

DayBlock[] blockWeekdays = {
new DayBlock {DayOfWeek=DayOfWeek.Tuesday, Start=TimeSpan.FromHours(17), End=TimeSpan.FromHours(24)},
new DayBlock {DayOfWeek=DayOfWeek.Wednesday, Start=TimeSpan.FromHours(0), End=TimeSpan.FromHours(24)},
new DayBlock {DayOfWeek=DayOfWeek.Thursday, Start=TimeSpan.FromHours(0), End=TimeSpan.FromHours(24)},
new DayBlock {DayOfWeek=DayOfWeek.Friday, Start=TimeSpan.FromHours(0), End=TimeSpan.FromHours(12)},
};
```

And how to include the hours and minutes in the `DayBlock`'s timespans, because currently just can add hours in the time span, if the start time or end time includes minutes, how can I add them in the DayBlock?

I tried below the code but it doesn't work:

```cs
//startDate = 22 Nov 2022 05:30 PM
//endDate = 25 Nov 2022 1:15 PM

class DayBlock
{
  public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; set; }
  public TimeSpan Start { get; set; }
  public TimeSpan End { get; set; }
}

DayBlock[] blockWeekdays = {
new DayBlock {DayOfWeek=DayOfWeek.Tuesday, Start=TimeSpan.FromHours(17:30), End=TimeSpan.FromHours(24)},
new DayBlock {DayOfWeek=DayOfWeek.Wednesday, Start=TimeSpan.FromHours(0), End=TimeSpan.FromHours(24)},
new DayBlock {DayOfWeek=DayOfWeek.Thursday, Start=TimeSpan.FromHours(0), End=TimeSpan.FromHours(24)},
new DayBlock {DayOfWeek=DayOfWeek.Friday, Start=TimeSpan.FromHours(0), End=TimeSpan.FromHours(13:15)},
};
```

I hope someone can help me solve the problem.

Comment: Would `TimeSpan.Parse("17:30")` work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You may use a loop to iterate the days between `startDate` and `endDate`, creating a `DayBlock` object for each one.  Here's an example:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2022, 11, 22, 17, 30, 0);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2022, 11, 25, 13, 15, 0);

if (endDate < startDate)
    throw new Exception("Bad input");

int days = (int)Math.Ceiling((endDate - startDate).TotalDays);
var blockWeekdays = new DayBlock[days];
for (int i = 0; i < days; i++)
{
    blockWeekdays[i] =
        new DayBlock
        {
            DayOfWeek = startDate.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek,
            Start = (i == 0 ? startDate.TimeOfDay : TimeSpan.Zero),
            End = (i == days - 1 ? endDate.TimeOfDay : TimeSpan.FromHours(24))
        };
}
```

This will also include the exact time of the DateTime (i.e., hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds, etc.).